# Exception handling with method chaining

Tags: python-3.x, exception

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def first():
        # Some functionality
        # raise Exception on some condition
        return self
    def second():
       #Some functionality

a = A('test string').first().second()
```

In this case I want that if first() raises an error then the chaining breaks and that error is raised. Currently it just fails silently.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there a `try-except` statement that's catching the exception from `first()`? It is otherwise impossible that your code is failing silently.

Comment: Show code that actually reproduces the issue.

Comment: My bad. Due to some condition the exception was getting caught somewhere down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best you can do is localize the type of errors that are possible in the chain and then ladder the exception handlers:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def first(self):
        # Some functionality
        # raise Exception on some condition
        if self.data=='A':
            1/0
        return self
    def second(self):
        next(0)
        pass
       #Some functionality
```

You would know that `first` is numerical, and `second` is an iterable function that might have a TypeError.

So try this:

```
try:
    A('A').first().second() 
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print('Likely first:', e)   
except TypeError as e:
    print('Likely second:', e)
```

Would print `Likely first: division by zero` with `A('A')` and print `Likely second: 'int' object is not an iterator` if you use `A('something_else')`. You would use this construct if you wanted to stop the chain as executed.

You can also add `raise` to re-raise the error and get Python's diagnosis of when are where:

```
try:
    A('B').first().second() 
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print('Likely first:', e)   
    raise
except TypeError as e:
    print('Likely second:', e)
    raise
```

Prints:

```
Likely second: 'int' object is not an iterator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled 79.py", line 19, in <module>
    A('B').first().second() 
  File "Untitled 79.py", line 14, in second
    next(0)
TypeError: 'int' object is not an iterator
```

Or, better still, use the `try` and `except` in each method:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def first(self):
        try: 
            1/0
        except ZeroDivisionError as e:
            print('DEFINITELY first:', e)       
        return self
    def second(self):
        try: 
            next(0)
        except TypeError as e:
            print('DEFINITELY second:', e)      
        return self

>>> A('').first().second()
DEFINITELY first: division by zero
DEFINITELY second: 'int' object is not an iterator
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it could fail silently if its actually failing, as this would error out python. However, you might want something like this, maybe it will jog your thinking.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def first():
        try:
            # Some functionality
            raise ERROR_YOU WANT_RAISE:

        # raise Exception on some condition
        except ERROR_TO_CATCH_FROM_RAISE:
            # This is where you would handle the exception after its caught
            # and break your chaining possibly. Set a flag for second() 
            # for example that handles the error.

        return self

    def second():
       #Some functionality
```